# Center Overlay in Parent

Tags: jquery, css, overlay

Here's yet another centered overlay question with a twist. I need to center an overlay in it's parent's container.

Complications

1. If the container is longer than the screen (I.e. vertical scroll bar), I need the overlay vertically centered in screen and horizontally centered in parent
2. If the contain fits in screen (I.e. no vertical sidebars), I need the overlay centered, horizontally and vertically, in parent container.

I currently have the overlay centered to screen in both scenarios.

Please see [my homepage](http://mattskelton.ca) (try the pager below the two services) and [service list](http://mattskelton.ca/service/index) (use the pager) for examples.

My current CSS for screen centering is

```
.overlay {
    display: none;
    padding: 20px 0;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background: #E9F7FF;
    border: 3px solid #97D1F4;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: #97D1F4;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 300px;
    height: 20px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -10px;
    margin-left: -150px;
}
```

Yes, I can use jQuery for this to work. CSS only would be ideal though.

Answer (score 0):

Used jQuery UI to solve - quite simple actually.

```
function isScrolledIntoView(elem)
{
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

    return ((docViewTop < elemTop) && (docViewBottom > elemBottom));
}

if (isScrolledIntoView(container))
        {
            $(overlay).position({
                my: "center",
                at: "center",
                of: $(container)
            });
        }
        else
        {
            $(overlay).position({
                my: "center",
                at: "center",
                of: window
            });
        }

        $(overlay).show();
}
```

Still need to find a way to vertically center to window and horizontally center to parent container but this works for now.